# eth.getTransaction returning null? Troubleshooting steps

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

Why am I getting null trying to query ANY transaction id? Any ideas to troubleshoot?

Running in light mode. I can query last block number. I can query balances of addresses without issue. eth.getTransaction returns null no matter what id. We have another node with practically the same settings in config and it works fine. Server is running NTP so server time is synced. Does it take along time to get more peers? Our other node has 12 peers.

Geth console...

```
instance: Geth/v1.8.6-stable-12683fec/linux-amd64/go1.10
modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 
txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> net.peerCount
6
> eth.getTransaction('INSERT ID HERE')
null
> net.listening
true
> eth.blockNumber
5541535
```

Comment: Could you test if it also returns `null` on very old transactions? I have this issue on test net but the problem seemed to go away when I probe old transactions.

Comment: A comment on Reddit suggests that light nodes cannot call `getTransaction`. https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/8gfjfq/node_help_ethgettransaction_returning_null/